# Canvas won't follow fullscreen window?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, window, size

I got the layer as follows:

```
<Window>
  <Grid>
     <Scrollviewer>
        <Canvas>
          ....
        <Canvas/>
     <Scrollviewer/>
  <Grid/>
<Window/>
```

Now if I want my grid to expand and follow the window height and width I use the following code:

```
<Window Title="MainWindow" Name="Window" MinHeight="500" MinWidth="800">

<Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=Height}" Width="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=Width}" x:Name="theGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="436*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,50,15,66">
        <Canvas MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=theGrid, Path=Width}" MinHeight="{Binding ElementName=theGrid, Path=Height}" Name="canvas1">
                <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider1}"
                                    ScaleY="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider1}"/>
                </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

This works fine when I'm resizing the window by pulling the sides/corners of the window..
!BUT! when I hit the "fullscreen" button in the top right corner it only shows the grid size of the last pictured grid. Like this:

[image: Grid is in the middle of the Window]

Its like it doesnt repaint the grid after "fullscreening" ..
Help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you are explicitly setting the `Width` and `Height` of the grid?
Setting the grids `Margin` to 0 will always set the Grid to the window size

```
    <Grid Margin="0" x:Name="theGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="436*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

 <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,50,15,66">
        <Canvas Margin="0" Name="canvas1">
                <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider1}"
                                    ScaleY="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider1}"/>
                </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: If I do this then my scrollviewers will never display